# Setting up Firebase database data/rules to make user's post publicly viewable

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm creating a study card application using Firebase real-time database and I want a user to be able to share a deck publicly. That means any user can see the creator's deck but only the creator can edit. I'm having trouble setting up the Firebase rules / data structure that would allow this to happen.

The way it works right now is that any public deck is pushed to a 'publicDecks' node, getting its own unique id, with the following structure:

```
-publicDecks
   |
   +jiEFJfehihxi (unique deck id)
     |+cards 
     |-deckName:"spanish vocab"
     |-uid:"iawojefiaofiojfweaf" (creator's uid)
```

In my rules, I want any authenticated user to be able to push a new deck to this node. But, if the user tries to update an existing deck, I want the rules to make sure the user's auth.uid matches the uid property attached to the existing deck.

I set up my rules like this:

```
"publicDecks": {
        ".read": "auth != null", 
      "$deck":{
        ".write": "auth!=null && root.child('publicDecks').child($deck).child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
      }
```

The problem right now is that these rules don't let the user create a new public deck. The user can only edit a child that already exists. How can I fix this....is it more a matter of my rules, or changing how I structure the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking up the deck from `root`, you are getting the data as it currently exists in the database. And that means that you won't get a deck when you first create it.

But you don't need to look up the current deck from `root` anyway. Instead you can start from `data` or `newData`, with the latter having the data as it will exist after the current write operation (if that one is allowed).

So it'll be something like:

```
"publicDecks": {
  ".read": "auth != null", 
  "$deck":{
    ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

---

You'll typically want to secure this slightly further to ensure that users can't claim somebody else's deck by writing their own UID into an existing deck. That'd be:

```
"$deck":{
  ".write": "(!data.child('uid').exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)
             || data.child('uid').val() == newData.child('uid').val()"
}
```

I'd typically move these rules into the `uid` child, to make them a bit shorter:

```
"$deck":{
  "uid": {
    ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.val() == auth.uid)
               || data.val() == newData.val()"
}
```